# Simple Array program - Basic JAVA " middleValie

Tags: java, arrays

" Given an array of integers, return the middle value if the length is odd, return the average of the two middle values if the length is even, and return zero if the length is zero.

```
middleValue([9, 8, 6, 9, 9]) → 6.0
middleValue([2, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2]) → 4.0
middleValue([1, 6, 5, 4, 7, 2]) → 4.0 "
```

Having trouble figuring out how to call the the length of the array, check if it's odd or even and then proceed to do the odd method, " return the middle value" or even, "find the average of the middle two numbers and return that."

would like to know what array methods i could use & how the parameters for the for loop would look like if there even is one.

so far I have,

```
  double middleValue(int[] a) {

     return a.length;
  }
```

which

```
Expected    Run     
middleValue([9, 8, 6, 9, 9]) → 6.0  5.0 X   
middleValue([2, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2]) → 4.0    7.0 X   
middleValue([1, 6, 5, 4, 7, 2]) → 4.0   6.0 X   
middleValue([6]) → 6.0  1.0 X   
middleValue([]) → 0.0   0.0 OK  
middleValue([0, -2, -4]) → -2.0 3.0 X   
middleValue([8, 10]) → 9.0  2.0 X   
middleValue([4, 5, 5]) → 5.0    3.0 X   
other tests
X
```

so far passes the test of the array having 0

this is from a website called codingbat, can't figure out how the numbers get inputted, but would like to learn how to solve this.

Thanks.

here's a link to the problem 
http://codingbat.com/prob/p226577

Comment: Well you appear to know about `a.length`, which is how you find the length of an array. Now, do you know how to access an element of an array by index? If not, please read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html As for checking whether a number is odd or even... I suspect you'll find the answer to that with a bit of searching.

Answer (score 2):

The middle value of

```
middleValue([1, 6, 5, 4, 7, 2]) → 4.0 "
```

is based on (5+4)/2 giving 4. So the result is an **int** too, and an integer division is performed.

To get values from an array `int[] a` use `a[i]` as in:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

To check whether something is even, one can use the modulo operator `%` which gives the remainder by division (`42 % 9 == 6`) or `(x/y)*y + (x%y) == x`.

```
if (a.length == 0) {
    return 0;
}

// floor value of middle:
int middleIndex = a.length / 2; // 6 → 3, 7 → 3

if (a.length % 2 == 0) {
    // even
    ...
} else {
    // odd
    return a[middleIndex];
}
```

---

***A bad style one-liner:*** (for learning)

```
int middleValue(int[] a) {

    return a.length == 0 ? 0 : (a[a.length/2] + a[(a.length + 1)/2])/2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a commented example, which should describe the different steps :

```
double middleValue(int[] a) {

  // get the length of the array
  int arrayLength = a.length;

  // shortcut : if length is 0, retun immediately
  if(arrayLength == 0)
    return 0;

  // find the middle index :
  // length/2 will be rounded down to the smallest integer, giving you the middle index (array indexes start at 0)
  int middleIndex= arrayLength/2;

  // Length is even (the length is dividable by 2)
  if(arrayLength % 2 == 0){

    // return the average of the middle values
    return (a[middleIndex-1] + a[middleIndex])/2;

  }// Length is odd
  else{

    //return the value of the middle index
    return a[middleIndex];

  }
}
```

Comment: The even case should be  `(a[middleIndex] + a[middleIndex + 1])/2` though I think. But otherwise very helpful with comments and all.

Comment: @JoopEggen : You're right I completely misread that part. I had to go with `(a[middleIndex-1] + a[middleIndex])/2` for the even case, or an array of size 2 would go out of bounds with `middleIndex + 1` for instance. Thanks !

Comment: @berger curious why the difference between writing      (a[middleIndex-1] + a[middleIndex])/2

Comment: @RoyZohan, indexes starting at 0, let's take an array of size 6, `middleIndex` will be 3, and what you want are the third and the fourth values (the middle values), i.e indexes 2 and 3 of the array . Hence, you have to use `middleIndex-1` as the index of the first "middle value", and `middleIndex` as the index of the second one .